# Swift runtime error: Dictionary literal contains duplicate keys

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary

I'm making a simple dictionary, `[ABPropertyID : String ]`:

```
let propertyToMethod = [ 
    kABPersonInstantMessageProperty : "contactMethodInstantMessage",
    kABPersonEmailProperty : "contactMethodEmail",
    kABPersonPhoneProperty : "contactMethodPhoneCall" ]
```

This crashes at runtime with `Dictionary literal contains duplicate keys`. Seems like the keys of type `ABPropertyID` aren't resolved until runtime...? But either way, why would there be a duplicate among them when they're used to differentiate address book properties?

And also, why would they all be zero?:

```
println("kabIM: \(kABPersonInstantMessageProperty), kabEmail: \(kABPersonEmailProperty), kabPhone: \(kABPersonPhoneProperty)")
```

prints `kabIM: 0, kabEmail: 0, kabPhone: 0`.

I was working under the impression that they were compile-time constants with unique values. This is how they are declared in the library:

```
let kABPersonEmailProperty: ABPropertyID // Email(s) - kABMultiStringPropertyType
```

...

```
typealias ABPropertyID = Int32
```

Running on iphone 5, 8.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My original code compiles, but for some reason these are runtime "constants" that change values from 0 to something else at an unknown point.

I postponed the construction of the dictionary to after initialization of my object, and it works.

```
var propertyToMethod: [ABPropertyID : String] { get {
    println("kabIM: \(kABPersonInstantMessageProperty), kabEmail: \(kABPersonEmailProperty), kabPhone: \(kABPersonPhoneProperty)")
    return [ kABPersonInstantMessageProperty : contactMethodInstantMessage,
    kABPersonEmailProperty : contactMethodEmail,
    kABPersonPhoneProperty : contactMethodPhoneCall ] }
}
```

But I still can't be sure that it won't crash in the future...

Comment: According to the "duplicate" that I linked to, you have to call one of the address book "create" function before using these "constants", e.g. `ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions()`.

Comment: Thanks! I looked at that answer but couldn't find the quoted paragraph in the linked documentation.

Comment: I cannot find it either. But the linked-to answer seems still to be correct, after calling `ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions()` the ""constants"" evaluate to non-zero numbers.